# Transparent backround in GE?

Tags: game-engine

I am taking some screenshots in the game engine, but I wondered about something. Is there a way you can have your background of your scene be transparent? I can take the picture into a paint program and give a transparent background, but I've wondered if I can do this in the GE. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know screenshots do not know transparency.

As a workaround you can use a [chroma-key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) technique to determine the background. This means you use a background color that is not used somewhere else in the picture and use it as transparency. This way you can easily remove that portions in your image editor.

Comment: If screenshots don't know them, then I guess this is the best way. Thanks!